# Why is the comment privilege 50 rep

Tags: discussion, comments, privileges

Why is it necessary to need 50 rep to comment wouldn't 20 be fine, I have seen people post comments in answers because they were unable to comment. requiring 20 rep would make more sense. should this be changed?

Comment: I'd imagine that **most** of these cases come from brand new users (1 rep) so 20 would still be too high.  It is perhaps an issue, but if a user is going to ask a question based on the answer, they can just as easily click "Ask Question" and get rep that way.  It is ok if it gets marked as a dupe since it is another point of entry from search engines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Comments give you the power to bother any answerer on the site. This site is meant to be for experts, experts we want to retain; the best way to lose our experts is to drown them in notifications.

This is why the bar to comment is "so" high.

Comment: what if comments have to be reviewed if a user has 20 rep?

Comment: @qwertyk31: No, just... no.  Delaying comments would be a bad thing, and removing them because of basic review could cause more damage.

Comment: @qwertyk31 - It's not really that high. 1 answer with 5 upvotes (or 5 answers with 1 upvote each) would give someone enough rep.

Comment: @qwertyk31 Reviewing comments would make it worse, by bothering *all* review-level users currently using the site and requiring *two* of them to do extra review work. Besides, it's mostly the 1 rep users doing this, and they're not likely to notice the difference between answers and comments even if commenting was open to them, so making comments available might not even change anything.

Comment: I took me a while, cuz all I can do is ask questions. I don't know anything at all about technical aspects of games, but I still think 20 is too low. 30 maybe?

Comment: @the you can always answer questions :-) and in fact we prefer if you do.